# How to get login username from cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

My browser has logged in an internal webpage (e.g. A.html), which is based on a third_party django application.
I want to write another web application (e.g. B.html) to query some information from DB based on the login username of A.html by accessing the cookie.
Is there anyway to get the username of A.html in B.html with javascript?

Comment: Have you tried searching for javascript and cookies online? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie

Comment: Are the pages in the same domain?